# Is the HTTPS lock sign displayed if reasources are loaded from insecure sites?

Tags: tls, web-browser, http, mixed-content

We all know that if you visit a secure site which uses https, all modern browsers will show a padlock sign if it has a CA certified certificate. My questions are:

1. Suppose there is an image loaded in the page from an insecure site (for example, from a site having self signed certificate). But the original page URL is a genuine secure site. In such a case will the browser show a warning in the address bar instead of the padlock sign?
2. If the resources in the page are all ordered from secure site, but assume that there is a form in the page. On submit of the form it goes to an insecure REST API having self signed certificate and the UI uses the content from the insecure site in the next page. It is important to note that the UI resources and the JavaScript etc. are all loaded from secure site itself. What will be the behaviour of the browser in this scenario?

Comment: Details depend on the browser. But usually the browser will not load embedded insecure content in the first place, so there is no need to change this sign.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I understand that it depends upon the browser - but let's consider prominent browsers like Firefox, Chrome and Safari..

Comment: As I already said: *"... the browser will not load embedded insecure content in the first place"*.

Comment: In case you want to research this, the term for HTTP resources loaded on a HTTPS site is "mixed content".

Comment: Chrome has changed things recently... but they used to display the lock for mixed content :  https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html

Comment: Thanks Anders! The suggestion was really helpful.